# How to iterate a loop with index and element in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, enumeration

Is there a function that I can use to iterate over an array and have both index and element, like Python's `enumerate`?

```
for index, element in enumerate(list):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1969, accepted):

Yes. As of Swift 3.0, if you need the index for each element along with its value, you can use the [`enumerated()` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_177) to iterate over the array. It returns a sequence of pairs composed of the index and the value for each item in the array. For example:

```
for (index, element) in list.enumerated() {
  print("Item \(index): \(element)")
}
```

Before Swift 3.0 and after Swift 2.0, the function was called `enumerate()`:

```
for (index, element) in list.enumerate() {
    print("Item \(index): \(element)")
}
```

Prior to Swift 2.0, `enumerate` was a global function.

```
for (index, element) in enumerate(list) {
    println("Item \(index): \(element)")
}
```

Comment: Although it seems like a tuple, in Swift 1.2 - not sure about 2.0 - enumerate returns an EnumerateSequence<base: SequenceType> struct.

Comment: @Leviathlon noticeable or measurable performance overhead that will matter? No.

Comment: is getting access to the index the only benefit of using `enumerate`?

Comment: Maybe they'll change to the gerund, `enumerating` for Swift 4. Exciting!

Comment: @Honey you are not getting any index there. You are getting the offset which is different. It works for arrays but If you enumerate a slice don't use the offset to subscript your collection. Use the collection indices. Not all collections starts at index zero.

Comment: @Honey `for (index, element) in` when using `enumerated` is misleading. should be `for (offset, element) in`

Comment: Do we hold a  sweepstakes as to who can guess what it'll change to next. This damn language just can't sit still lol

Answer (score 159):

Swift 5 provides a method called [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) for `Array`. `enumerated()` has the following declaration:

```
func enumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<Array<Element>>
```

> Returns a sequence of pairs (n, x), where n represents a consecutive integer starting at zero and x represents an element of the sequence.

---

In the simplest cases, you may use `enumerated()` with a for loop. For example:

```
let list = ["Car", "Bike", "Plane", "Boat"]
for (index, element) in list.enumerated() {
    print(index, ":", element)
}

/*
prints:
0 : Car
1 : Bike
2 : Plane
3 : Boat
*/
```

---

Note however that you're not limited to use `enumerated()` with a for loop. In fact, if you plan to use `enumerated()` with a for loop for something similar to the following code, you're doing it wrong:

```
let list = [Int](1...5)
var arrayOfTuples = [(Int, Int)]()

for (index, element) in list.enumerated() {
    arrayOfTuples += [(index, element)]
}

print(arrayOfTuples) // prints [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

A swiftier way to do this is:

```
let list = [Int](1...5)
let arrayOfTuples = Array(list.enumerated())
print(arrayOfTuples) // prints [(offset: 0, element: 1), (offset: 1, element: 2), (offset: 2, element: 3), (offset: 3, element: 4), (offset: 4, element: 5)]
```

---

As an alternative, you may also use `enumerated()` with `map`:

```
let list = [Int](1...5)
let arrayOfDictionaries = list.enumerated().map { (a, b) in return [a : b] }
print(arrayOfDictionaries) // prints [[0: 1], [1: 2], [2: 3], [3: 4], [4: 5]]
```

---

Moreover, although it has some [limitations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018369-foreach), `forEach` can be a good replacement to a for loop:

```
let list = [Int](1...5)
list.reversed().enumerated().forEach { print($0, ":", $1) }

/*
prints:
0 : 5
1 : 4
2 : 3
3 : 2
4 : 1
*/
```

---

By using `enumerated()` and `makeIterator()`, you can even iterate manually on your `Array`. For example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var generator = ["Car", "Bike", "Plane", "Boat"].enumerated().makeIterator()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Tap", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(iterate(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func iterate(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let tuple = generator.next()
        print(String(describing: tuple))
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()

/*
 Optional((offset: 0, element: "Car"))
 Optional((offset: 1, element: "Bike"))
 Optional((offset: 2, element: "Plane"))
 Optional((offset: 3, element: "Boat"))
 nil
 nil
 nil
 */
```

Comment: Is getting access to the index the only benefit of using `enumerate`?

Answer (score 60):

Starting with Swift 2, the enumerate function needs to be called on the collection like so:

```
for (index, element) in list.enumerate() {
    print("Item \(index): \(element)")
}
```

Answer (score 54):

I found this answer while looking for a way to do that with a **Dictionary**, and it turns out it's quite easy to adapt it, just pass a tuple for the element.

```
// Swift 2

var list = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

for (index, (letter, value)) in list.enumerate() {
    print("Item \(index): \(letter) \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 50):

**Swift 5.x:**

**let list =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]**

```
list.enumerated().forEach { (index, value) in
    print("index: \(index), value: \(value)")
}
```

Or,

```
list.enumerated().forEach { 
    print("index: \($0.offset), value: \($0.element)")
}
```

Or,

```
for (index, value) in list.enumerated() {
    print("index: \(index), value: \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 37):

For completeness you can simply iterate over your array indices and use subscript to access the element at the corresponding index:

```
let list = [100,200,300,400,500]
for index in list.indices {
    print("Element at:", index, " Value:", list[index])
}
```

Using forEach

```
list.indices.forEach {
    print("Element at:", $0, " Value:", list[$0])
}
```

Using collection `enumerated()` method. Note that it returns a collection of tuples with the `offset` and the `element`:

```
for item in list.enumerated() {
    print("Element at:", item.offset, " Value:", item.element)
}
```

using forEach:

```
list.enumerated().forEach {
    print("Element at:", $0.offset, " Value:", $0.element)
}
```

---

Those will print

> Element at: 0  Value: 100
>
> Element at: 1  Value: 200
>
> Element at: 2  Value: 300
>
> Element at: 3  Value: 400
>
> Element at: 4  Value: 500

If you need the array index (not the offset) and its element you can extend Collection and create your own method to get the indexed elements:

```
extension Collection {
    func indexedElements(body: ((index: Index, element: Element)) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        var index = startIndex
        for element in self {
            try body((index,element))
            formIndex(after: &index)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another possible implementation as suggested by Alex is to zip the collection indices with its elements:

```
extension Collection {
    func indexedElements(body: ((index: Index, element: Element)) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        for element in zip(indices, self) { try body(element) }
    }
    var indexedElements: Zip2Sequence<Indices, Self> { zip(indices, self) }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let list =  ["100","200","300","400","500"]

// You can iterate the index and its elements using a closure
list.dropFirst(2).indexedElements {
    print("Index:", $0.index, "Element:", $0.element)
}

// or using a for loop
for (index, element) in list.indexedElements  {
    print("Index:", index, "Element:", element)
}
```

This will p[rint

> Index: 2 Element: 300
>
> Index: 3 Element: 400
>
> Index: 4 Element: 500
>
> Index: 0 Element: 100
>
> Index: 1 Element: 200
>
> Index: 2 Element: 300
>
> Index: 3 Element: 400
>
> Index: 4 Element: 500

Comment: BTW you can implement `enumeratedIndices` by looping over with `zip(self.indices, self)`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica        `for element in zip(indices, self) {
            try body(element)
        }`. Btw I don't like the naming I chose, `indexedElements` might describe better what it does

Comment: Ooo I think that's a better name. Yeah, a `for` loop works, but also `zip(self.indices, self) .forEach(body)`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica `forEach` does a for loop behind the scenes. I prefer to keep it plain simple https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift `@inlinable
  public func forEach(
    _ body: (Element) throws -> Void
  ) rethrows {
    for element in self {
      try body(element)
    }
  }
}`

Comment: for index in list.indices is brilliant @LeoDabus !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 35):

### Swift 5.x:

I personally prefer using the `forEach` method:

```
list.enumerated().forEach { (index, element) in
    ...
}
```

You can also use the short version:

```
list.enumerated().forEach { print("index: \($0.0), value: \($0.1)") }
```

Comment: Interesting tidbit for forEach cannot return a value - Unexpected non-void return value in void function. So return the result afterwards.

Comment: You also won't be able to skip a loop if need be

Answer (score 25):

You can simply use loop of enumeration to get your desired result:

**Swift 2:**

```
for (index, element) in elements.enumerate() {
    print("\(index): \(element)")
}
```

**Swift 3 & 4:**

```
for (index, element) in elements.enumerated() {
    print("\(index): \(element)")
}
```

Or you can simply go through a for loop to get the same result:

```
for index in 0..<elements.count {
    let element = elements[index]
    print("\(index): \(element)")
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 19):

#### Basic enumerate

```
for (index, element) in arrayOfValues.enumerate() {
// do something useful
}
```

or with Swift 3...

```
for (index, element) in arrayOfValues.enumerated() {
// do something useful
}
```

#### Enumerate, Filter and Map

However, I most often use enumerate in combination with map or filter. For example with operating on a couple of arrays.

In this array I wanted to filter odd or even indexed elements and convert them from Ints to Doubles. So `enumerate()` gets you index and the element, then filter checks the index, and finally to get rid of the resulting tuple I map it to just the element.

```
let evens = arrayOfValues.enumerate().filter({
                            (index: Int, element: Int) -> Bool in
                            return index % 2 == 0
                        }).map({ (_: Int, element: Int) -> Double in
                            return Double(element)
                        })
let odds = arrayOfValues.enumerate().filter({
                            (index: Int, element: Int) -> Bool in
                            return index % 2 != 0
                        }).map({ (_: Int, element: Int) -> Double in
                            return Double(element)
                        })
```

Answer (score 13):

Using `.enumerate()` works, but it does not provide the true index of the element; it only provides an Int beginning with 0 and incrementing by 1 for each successive element. This is usually irrelevant, but there is the potential for unexpected behavior when used with the `ArraySlice` type. Take the following code:

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
a.indices //=> 0..<5

let aSlice = a[1..<4] //=> ArraySlice with ["b", "c", "d"]
aSlice.indices //=> 1..<4

var test = [Int: String]()
for (index, element) in aSlice.enumerate() {
    test[index] = element
}
test //=> [0: "b", 1: "c", 2: "d"] // indices presented as 0..<3, but they are actually 1..<4
test[0] == aSlice[0] // ERROR: out of bounds
```

It's a somewhat contrived example, and it's not a common issue in practice but still I think it's worth knowing this can happen.

Comment: `it does not actually provide the true index of the element; it only provides an Int beginning with 0 and incrementing by 1 for each successive element` Yes, that's why it's called *enumerate*. Also, slice is not array, so no surprise it behaves differently. There's no bug here - everything is by design. :)

Comment: True, but I never called it a bug. It just is potentially unexpected behavior that I thought was worth mentioning for those who didn't know how it could interact negatively with the ArraySlice type.

Comment: Are you aware of any way to get the index of the actual element - for example if using `filter` first?

Answer (score 12):

Starting with Swift 3, it is

```
for (index, element) in list.enumerated() {
  print("Item \(index): \(element)")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the Formula of loop of Enumeration:

```
for (index, value) in shoppingList.enumerate() {
print("Item \(index + 1): \(value)")
}
```

for more detail you can check [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105).

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 8 and Swift 3: 
Array can be enumerated using `tempArray.enumerated()`

Example:

```
var someStrs = [String]()

someStrs.append("Apple")  
someStrs.append("Amazon")  
someStrs += ["Google"]    


for (index, item) in someStrs.enumerated()  
{  
        print("Value at index = \(index) is \(item)").  
}
```

console:

```
Value at index = 0 is Apple
Value at index = 1 is Amazon
Value at index = 2 is Google
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who want to use `forEach`.

Swift 4

```
extension Array {
  func forEachWithIndex(_ body: (Int, Element) throws -> Void) rethrows {
    try zip((startIndex ..< endIndex), self).forEach(body)
  }
}
```

Or

```
array.enumerated().forEach { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

For what you are wanting to do, you should use the `enumerated()` method on your **Array**:

```
for (index, element) in list.enumerated() {
    print("\(index) - \(element)")
}
```

Comment: enumerated() was the magic spell I was looking for.... that fixed my 'uple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type 'Items'' error.. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 6):

Use .enumerated() like this in functional programming:

```
list.enumerated().forEach { print($0.offset, $0.element) }
```

Answer (score 6):

In **iOS 8.0**/**Swift 4.0**+

You can use `forEach`
As per the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach):

> Returns a sequence of pairs (n, x), where n represents a consecutive integer starting at zero and x represents an element of the sequence.

```
let numberWords = ["one", "two", "three"]

numberWords.enumerated().forEach { (key, value) in
   print("Key: \(key) - Value: \(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you for whatever reason want a more traditional looking `for` loop that accesses the elements in the array using their index:

```swift
let xs = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

for i in 0 ..< xs.count {
    print("\(i) - \(xs[i])")
}
```

Output:

```
0 - A
1 - B
2 - C
3 - D
```

Answer (score 1):

It's critical to note that Apple now does guarantee that the order is "correct"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/foreach(_:)

### "Calls the given closure on each element in the sequence *in the same order as a for-in loop*" (Apple doco).

```
.enumerated().forEach { print("\($0.offset) \($0.element)") }
```

Answer (score -1):

We called enumerate function to implements this. like

```
    for (index, element) in array.enumerate() {
     index is indexposition of array
     element is element of array 
   }
```