# Variadic method in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Objective C Code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithInts:(int32_t)int1, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, int1);
    unsigned int length = 0;
    for (int32_t i = int1; i != -1; i = va_arg(args, int)) {
        length ++;
    }
    va_end(args);
    ...
    ...
    return self;
}
```

This code is used to count the numbers of method's parameters.

Swift Code:

```
convenience init(ints: Int32, _ args: CVarArgType...) {
    var length: UInt = 0
    self.init(length: args.count)
    withVaList(args, { _ in
        // How to increase length' value in loop?
    })
}
```

What's the best practise to use `withVaList` to loop through the argument list with a `CVaListPointer`? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just

```
convenience init(args: Int...) {
  return args.count
}
```

Comment: What if I need to access the index of element in va_list ? likes do something like `array[i++] = arg;`

Comment: you mean while looping? In that case you loop over `ints.enumerate()`, which gives you also the index. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array

Comment: Maybe `args`, rather than `ints`?

Answer (score 1):

```
convenience required init(args: Int32...) {

}
```

If you define your func parameter following by three dots `...`, you will notice `args` is actually a `[Int32]` type.

So just do casting likes `Array`, i.e. `args.count`, `for i in args`.