# Swift 3 for loop with increment

Tags: swift, swift3

How do I write the following in Swift3?

```
for (f = first; f <= last; f += interval)          
{
    n += 1
}
```

This is my own attempt

```
for _ in 0.stride(to: last, by: interval)
{
    n += 1
}
```

Answer (score 72):

#### Swift 2.2 -> 3.0: `Strideable`:s `stride(...)` replaced by global `stride(...)` functions

In Swift 2.2, we can (as you've tried in your own attempt) make use of the blueprinted (and default-implemented) functions `stride(through:by:)` and `stride(to:by:)` [from the protocol `Strideable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/Strideable/)

> ```
> /* Swift 2.2: stride example usage */
> let from = 0
> let to = 10
> let through = 10
> let by = 1
> for _ in from.stride(through, by: by) { } // from ... through (steps: 'by')
> for _ in from.stride(to, by: by) { }      // from ..< to      (steps: 'by')
> ```

Whereas in Swift 3.0, these two functions has been removed from `Strideable` in favour of [the global functions `stride(from:through:by:)` and `stride(from:to:by:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/func/stride/); hence the equivalent Swift 3.0 version of the above follows as

> ```
> /* Swift 3.0: stride example usage */
> let from = 0
> let to = 10
> let through = 10
> let by = 1
> for _ in stride(from: from, through: through, by: by) { }
> for _ in stride(from: from, to: to, by: by) { }
> ```

In your example you want to use the closed interval stride alternative `stride(from:through:by:)`, since the invariant in your `for` loop uses comparison to less *or equal to* (`<=`). I.e.

```
/* example values of your parameters 'first', 'last' and 'interval' */
let first = 0
let last = 10
let interval = 2
var n = 0
for f in stride(from: first, through: last, by: interval) { 
    print(f)
    n += 1 
} // 0 2 4 6 8 10
print(n) // 6
```

Where, naturally, we use your `for` loop only as an example of the passage from `for` loop to `stride`, as you can naturally, for your specific example, just compute `n` without the need of a loop (`n=1+(last-first)/interval`).

#### Swift 3.0: An alternative to `stride` for more complex iterate increment logic

With [the implementation of evolution proposal SE-0094](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0094-sequence-function.md), Swift 3.0 introduced the global `sequence` functions:

- [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2015879-sequence),
- [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2011998-sequence),

which can be an appropriate alternative to `stride` for cases with a more complex iterate increment relation (which is not the case in this example).

> **Declaration(s)**
>
> ```
> func sequence<T>(first: T, next: @escaping (T) -> T?) -> 
>          UnfoldSequence<T, (T?, Bool)>
>
> func sequence<T, State>(state: State, 
>                         next: @escaping (inout State) -> T?) ->
>            UnfoldSequence<T, State>
> ```

We'll briefly look at the first of these two functions. The `next` arguments takes a closure that applies some logic to lazily construct next sequence element given the current one (starting with `first`). The sequence is terminated when `next` returns `nil`, or infinite, if a `next` never returns `nil`.

Applied to the simple constant-stride example above, the `sequence` method is a bit verbose and overkill w.r.t. the fit-for-this-purpose `stride` solution:

```
let first = 0
let last = 10
let interval = 2
var n = 0
for f in sequence(first: first,
                  next: { $0 + interval <= last ? $0 + interval : nil }) {
    print(f)
    n += 1
} // 0 2 4 6 8 10
print(n) // 6
```

The `sequence` functions become very useful for cases with non-constant stride, however, e.g. as in the example covered in the following Q&A:

- [Express for loops in swift with dynamic range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070202/express-for-loops-in-swift-with-dynamic-range/40070339#comment67417397_40070339)

Just take care to terminate the sequence with an eventual `nil` return (if not: "infinite" element generation), or, when Swift 3.1 arrives, make use of its lazy generation in combination with the `prefix(while:)` method for sequences, as described in evolution proposal [SE-0045](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0045-scan-takewhile-dropwhile.md). The latter applied to the running example of this answer makes the `sequence` approach less verbose, clearly including the termination criteria of the element generation.

```
/* for Swift 3.1 */
// ... as above
for f in sequence(first: first, next: { $0 + interval })
    .prefix(while: { $0 <= last }) {
    print(f)
    n += 1
} // 0 2 4 6 8 10
print(n) // 6
```

Comment: weren't we moving away from global functions in Swift 2, and now returning to them in Swift 3? <<sigh>>

Comment: What is the equivalent of stride in newer version of swift?

Answer (score 40):

With Swift 5, you may choose one of the 5 following examples in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `stride(from:to:by:)` function

```
let first = 0
let last = 10
let interval = 2

let sequence = stride(from: first, to: last, by: interval)

for element in sequence {
    print(element)
}

/*
prints:
0
2
4
6
8
*/
```

---

### #2. Using `sequence(first:next:)` function

```
let first = 0
let last = 10
let interval = 2

let unfoldSequence = sequence(first: first, next: {
    $0 + interval < last ? $0 + interval : nil
})

for element in unfoldSequence {
    print(element)
}

/*
prints:
0
2
4
6
8
*/
```

---

### #3. Using `AnySequence` `init(_:)` initializer

```
let anySequence = AnySequence<Int>({ () -> AnyIterator<Int> in
    let first = 0
    let last = 10
    let interval = 2

    var value = first
    return AnyIterator<Int> {
        defer { value += interval }
        return value < last ? value : nil
    }
})

for element in anySequence {
    print(element)
}

/*
prints:
0
2
4
6
8
*/
```

---

### #4. Using `CountableRange` `filter(_:)` method

```
let first = 0
let last = 10
let interval = 2

let range = first ..< last
let lazyCollection = range.lazy.filter({ $0 % interval == 0 })

for element in lazyCollection {
    print(element)
}

/*
prints:
0
2
4
6
8
*/
```

---

### #5. Using `CountableRange` `flatMap(_:)` method

```
let first = 0
let last = 10
let interval = 2

let range = first ..< last
let lazyCollection = range.lazy.compactMap({ $0 % interval == 0 ? $0 : nil })

for element in lazyCollection {
    print(element)
}

/*
prints:
0
2
4
6
8
*/
```

Comment: For the simplest case where `interval` is 1, the latest version of Swift lets you use the very compact `for _ in 0...5 { n += 1 }`.  The disadvantage of this method is that unlike the solutions in the answer, it doesn't let you specify intervals other than 1.

Answer (score 15):

Simply, working code for Swift 3.0:

```
let (first, last, interval) = (0, 100, 1)
var n = 0
for _ in stride(from: first, to: last, by: interval) {
    n += 1
}
```

Comment: If you're going through an array and want an index, too, you can use `enumerated()` as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24028458/8047

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `while` loop as alternative way

```swift
while first <= last {
    first += interval
}
```

Answer (score -5):

for _ in 0.stride(to: last, by: interval)
                {
                    n += 1
                }

Comment: You cannot say `0.stride` in Swift 3.