# Swift's stride(from: , to: , by: ) causing "cannot invoke"

Tags: swift, stride

I'm using Swift's stride for the first time. However first is on the verge of being the last since I can't get this to work:

```
let boundingBox = createdShape.frame //=SKShapeNode
stride(from: Int(boundingBox.minX), to: Int(boundingBox.maxX), by: 10) {
```

The result is:

> Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: Int, to: Int, by: Int, () -> ())'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the stride? Iterate though it?

Comment: This is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170203/swift-3-for-loop-with-increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
let boundingBox = createdShape.frame //=SKShapeNode
for x in stride(from: Int(boundingBox.minX), to: Int(boundingBox.maxX), by: 10) {
  // TODO: Use x here.
}
```