# Iterating through all but the last index of an array

Tags: swift, swift3

I understand that in Swift 3 there have been some changes from typical C Style for-loops. I've been working around it, but it seems like I'm writing more code than before in many cases. Maybe someone can steer me in the right direction because this is what I want:

```
let names : [String] = ["Jim", "Jenny", "Earl"]
for var i = 0; i < names.count - 1; i+=1 {
    NSLog("%@ loves %@", names[i], names[i+1])
}
```

Pretty simple stuff. I like to be able to get the index I'm on, and I like the for-loop to not run if names.count == 0. All in one go.

But it seems like my options in Swift 3 aren't allowing me this. I would have to do something like:

```
let names : [String] = ["Jim", "Jenny", "Earl"]
if names.count > 0 {
    for i in 0...(names.count - 1) {
        NSLog("%@ loves %@", names[i], names[i+1])
    }
}
```

The if statement at the start is needed because my program will crash in the situation where it reads: for i in 0...0 { }

I also like the idea of being able to just iterate through everything without explicitly setting the index:

```
// Pseudocode
for name in names.exceptLastOne {
    NSLog("%@ loves %@", name, name.plus(1))
}
```

I feel like there is some sort of syntax that mixes all my wants, but I haven't come across it yet. Does anyone know of a way? Or at least a way to make my code more compact?

UPDATE: Someone suggested that this question has already been asked, citing a SO post where the solution was to use something to the degree of:

```
for (index, name) in names.enumerated {}
```

The problem with this when compared to Hamish's answer is that I only am given the index of the current name. That doesn't allow me to get the value at index without needing to do something like:

```
names[index + 1]
```

That's just one extra variable to keep track of. I prefer Hamish's which is:

```
for i in names.indices.dropLast() {
    print("\(names[i]) loves \(names[i + 1])")
}
```

Short, simple, and only have to keep track of names and i, rather than names, index, and name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift for loop: for index, element in array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array)

Comment: `for name in names.dropLast() {`

Comment: @LeoDabus But the OP needs to access two different objects from the array during each iteration.

Comment: `for (index, name) in names.dropLast().enumerated() {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Post an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Hamish already posted a similar approach

Comment: Note that you can (and indeed should) drop the explicit type annotation from `names` and use `print` with string interpolation rather than `NSLog`.

Comment: @Hamish not that it has to do with the original question, but why should I use print rather than NSLog? I was using print for a bit, but then for my macOS app, I would sometimes get into certain files and try print, but I ended up getting a popup saying I couldn't print (while running the app). So in order to not have to think about it anymore, I got back into the habit of NSLog. Also, why drop explicit type annotation? I thought doing that speeds up compiler.

Comment: @Kjell I agree that there are some cases where you need to use `NSLog`, and your situation may well be one of them – but in general you should prefer to use `print`, as `NSLog` only works with (bridgeable to) Objective-C types (e.g if you try and `NSLog` a custom Swift type, you'll get a compiler error). In addition, `print` allows you to customise the output of a given custom type through conformance to `Custom(Debug)StringConvertible`. Omitting type annotations makes your code cleaner and easier to read – although there are indeed corner cases where they're needed to assist the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option would be to use [`dropLast()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641797-droplast) on the array's [`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687816-indices), allowing you to iterate over a `CountableRange` of all but the last index of the array.

```
let names = ["Jim", "Jenny", "Earl"]

for i in names.indices.dropLast() {
    print("\(names[i]) loves \(names[i + 1])")
}
```

If the array has less than two elements, the loop won't be entered.

Another option would be to [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip) the array with the array where the first element has been dropped, allowing you to iterate through the pairs of elements with their successor elements:

```
for (nameA, nameB) in zip(names, names.dropFirst()) {
    print("\(nameA) loves \(nameB)")
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `zip` truncates the longer of the two sequences if they aren't of equal length. Therefore if the array has less than two elements, again, the loop won't be entered.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about zip! That's awesome! Also didn't know about indicies.dropLast(). Will definately make use of that as I like having a reference to the index.