# How can I loop through an object in SwiftyJSON? not just with swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

```
var tempJSON:JSON = ""
tempJSON = JSON(self.userdefaults.string(forKey: "currentOrder"))
print(tempJSON)
```

yields:

```
{"7": "1", "21": "0", "20": "0", "3": "1"}
```

I need to be able to loop through this and just can't. 
I've tried.

```
for(key,value) in tempJSON{
       print(key)

            }
```

and nothing outputs....

Thanks

Comment: do `tempJSON.enumerated()` or simply just do `for item in tempJSON{ print(item)` <-- this won't give you the index, if you want the **index** then you must do use `enumerated()`

Comment: I'm sorry not sure how to do enumerated in swiftyjson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift for loop: for index, element in array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array)

Comment: Why does it not working? it working fine for me, dont need `enumerated()` since its `(key,value)` pair, not `(index,value)` pair

Answer (score 1):

Try getting `Data` from the string and use it to init the `JSON` object:

```
let jsonString = "{\"7\": \"1\", \"21\": \"0\", \"20\": \"0\", \"3\": \"1\"}"
if let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let tempJSON = JSON(data: dataFromString)
    print(tempJSON)

    for (key, value) in tempJSON {
        print(key)
        print(value.stringValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: @BostonMacOSX I have tried using a string and it worked for me. Try to check if your user defaults is returning the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
for(key,value) in tempJSON.enumerated(){
   print(key)
}
```

Comment: Don't need enumerated for printing JSON object, his code is correct, problem maybe lying elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are getting a string out from your userdefault and use it to init `JSON`, try change:

```
tempJSON = JSON(self.userdefaults.string(forKey: "currentOrder"))
```

to

```
tempJSON = JSON(self.userdefaults.dictionary(forKey: "currentOrder"))
```

Comment: Probably your userdefault value is not correct, tried with an Dictionary or Data like changesam answer both working

Comment: so how would I get the string I posted above to the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
I had to add the parseJSON: to the JSON method so as to tell that is was coming from a string literal.

```
var tempJSON:JSON = ""
tempJSON = JSON(parseJSON: self.userdefaults.string(forKey: "currentOrder"))
print(tempJSON)
```