# How to get the row index of 2D Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3

I am new to Swift and I am using a 2D array for comparing and I need to get the row index once the condition is true but I got an error state that `cannot invoke index with an argument list of type (of:Array<Float>)`

My Code:

```
var entryCoordinate: [[Float]] = [[130.6,61.0],[167.5,61.0],[204.5,61.0],[243.6,61.0],[281.16,61.0],[315.3,61.0]]

 for indexs in entryCoordinate
        {
            if indexs[0] == startPathPointX && indexs[1] == startPathPointY
            {
                let pathStartElement = indexs.index(of: indexs)
                print(pathStartElement)
            }

            if indexs[0] == endPathPointX && indexs[1] == endPathPointY
            {
                let pathEndElement = indexs.index(of: indexs)
                print(pathEndElement)
            }
        }
```

Comment: `indexs.index(of: indexs)` you meant `entryCoordinate.index(of: indexs)`, no? Else, if you have duplicates values, it should returns only the first elements found. Also `if indexs[0] == startPathPointX && indexs[1] == startPathPointY`, no?

Comment: yup if found i want to get the row index of entryCoordinate...so it is like getting which row is the value located

Comment: `for (index, aCoordindate) in entryCoordinate.enumerated() { if aCoordindate[0] == startX && aCoordindate[1] == startY { print("CoordinateFound: \(aCoordindate)"); print("Index: \(index)") } }` instead? For Loop with Index taken from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code with `startPathPointY` and `endPathPointY` you need to compare the second object from 2D array but you keep comparing the first one and you con use [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index) with your array like this to get the `pathStartElement` and `pathEndElement`.

```
if let pathStartElement = entryCoordinate.index(where: { $0[0] == startPathPointX && $0[1] == startPathPointY }) {
    print(pathStartElement)
}
if let pathEndElement = entryCoordinate.index(where: { $0[0] == endPathPointX && $0[1] == endPathPointY }) {
    print(pathEndElement)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let myIndexPathStartElement = self.arrImagetData.index(where: { $0[0] == startPathPointX && $0[1] == startPathPointY })

let myIndexPathEndElement = self.arrImagetData.index(where: { $0[0] == endPathPointX && $0[1] == endPathPointY })
```