# iOS Charts error Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I use in my app library **SwiftChart** and I want to create such view of chart:

[image]

My code:

```
    class MyViewController: UIViewController, ChartDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    lineChart.delegate = self
  }
// Chart delegate
func didTouchChart(_ chart: Chart, indexes: Array<Int?>, x: Double, left: CGFloat) {
    // Do something on touch
}

func didFinishTouchingChart(_ chart: Chart) {
    // Do something when finished
}

func didEndTouchingChart(_ chart: Chart) {
    // Do something when ending touching chart
}

func didTouchChart(chart: Chart, indexes: Array<Int?>, x: Double, left: CGFloat) {
    for (seriesIndex, dataIndex) in enumerate(indexes) {
        if dataIndex != nil {
            // The series at `seriesIndex` is that which has been touched
            let value = chart.valueForSeries(seriesIndex, atIndex: dataIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

But I received and error message:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'enumerate'

What's wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to be in earlier version of Swift (3 <), it be `indexes .enumerated`.

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array

Answer (score 1):

Change your code snippet inside "didTouchChart" function to:

```
for (seriesIndex, dataIndex) in indexes.enumerated() {
        if dataIndex != nil {
            // The series at `seriesIndex` is that which has been touched
            let value = chart.valueForSeries(seriesIndex, atIndex: dataIndex)
        }
}
```

This is the correct syntax from swift 3 and onwards.

Comment: Error disappear, but chart is not load, i have empty space

Comment: "This is the correct syntax in swift" you should complete the info by adding "since Swift 3 and above".

Comment: @BestMoments I would assume that the *syntax* is correct, displaying an empty space is another issue so far...

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks buddy, Edited the answer

Comment: @BestMoments Please ask this as another question.