# Getting "String.Index" while enumerating swift string

Tags: swift, string, swift-string

Currently we iterate string as below:

```
let greeting = "Hello"
for (intIndex, char) in greeting.enumerated() {
    let currentIndex = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: intIndex)
    let indexAfterCurrentIndex = greeting.index(after: currentIndex)
    print(greeting[indexAfterCurrentIndex...])
}
```

I feel writing below code is redundant.

```
let currentIndex = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: intIndex)
```

> **Is there other way to get directly "String.Index" while iterating?**

Something like this

```
let greeting = "Hello"
for (stringIndex, char) in greeting.enumeratedXXX() {
    let indexAfterCurrentIndex = greeting.index(after: stringIndex)
    print(greeting[indexAfterCurrentIndex...])
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877538/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this. You could wrap this in a custom iterator, but then you only encapsulate the same kind of computation in a different place, so that's not an answer :)

### Code Complexity

However, you can improve performance of your current code:

```
greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: intIndex)
```

- This will calculate the index from `startIndex` to the resulting index for every loop iteration.
- The index calculation with `index(_:offsetBy:)` is really just another loop itself, where it `+1`s each index. There's no `O(1)` way to "compute" the index; it is found out by a loop in `O(n)`

So your own outer loop is linear with `O(n)` for `n` iterations, one for every character.

Then computing the index with an inner loop means there are `1+2+3+4+5+6+...n = (n^2 + n)/2` iterations, where `n` is the `intIndex` in this case.

That means the algorithm has a complexity of *handwaiving* roundabout `O(n + n^2)`. The quadratic part is problematic!

### Better approach

You can get the complexity down to 2 operations per iteration, or `O(2n)`. Just keep the previously computed index in memory and +1 yourself, avoiding a recomputation from scratch.

Here's the code:

```swift
let greeting = "Hello"
var index = greeting.startIndex
for char in greeting {
    let indexAfterCurrentIndex = greeting.index(after: index)
    print(greeting[indexAfterCurrentIndex...])
    index = indexAfterCurrentIndex
}
```

Still not a simple and built-in solution, but you can just as well wrap this more efficient algorithm and off you go!

```swift
extension String {
    func forEachCharacterWithIndex(iterator: (String.Index, Character) -> Void) {
        var currIndex = self.startIndex
        for char in self {
            iterator(currIndex, char)
            currIndex = self.index(after: currIndex)
        }
    }
}

let greeting = "Hello"
greeting.forEachCharacterWithIndex { (index, char) in
    let indexAfterCurrentIndex = greeting.index(after: index)
    print(greeting[indexAfterCurrentIndex...])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the string indices then you can enumerate `greeting.indices`:

```
let greeting = "Hello"
for index in greeting.indices {
    // ...
}
```

If you need each character together with its index  then you can enumerate the string and the indices in parallel:

```
let greeting = "Hello"
for (char, currentIndex) in zip(greeting, greeting.indices) {
    let indexAfterCurrentIndex = greeting.index(after: currentIndex)
    print(char, "-", greeting[indexAfterCurrentIndex...])
}
```

Output:

```
H - ello
e - llo
l - lo
l - o
o -
```

A simpler variant would be

```
let greeting = "Hello"
for (char, nextIndex) in zip(greeting, greeting.indices.dropFirst()) {
    print(char, "-", greeting[nextIndex...])
}
```

which produces *almost* the same result, only without the last character/index pair:

```
H - ello
e - llo
l - lo
l - o
```

Comment: thanks, indices is pretty useful for something like zip(mutableSelf.indices, mutableSelf).compactMap { index, char in ... }

Answer (score -1):

Why not increment the currentIndex by 1 ?

```
let greeting = "Hello"
for (stringIndex, char) in greeting.enumerated() {
    let currentIndex = stringIndex
    let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
    print(nextIndex)
}
```

Comment: You cannot increment a `String.Index` with `+` and an `Int`

Comment: @ctietze enumerated() doesn't return an Index. It returns the element offset (an Int)

Comment: @LeoDabus Right, but that does not help when the OP wants to work with substrings (see title). `greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: intIndex + 1)` would be 1 line shorter, but it's the same problem