# Enumerate String from specific index in nested loop in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

To get characters from `String` using `enumerated()` method

```
let str = "Hello"

for (i,val) in str.enumerated() {
        print("\(i) -> \(val)")
}
```

now trying to enumerate same string inside `for` loop but from **i** position like

```
for (i,val) in str.enumerated() {
        print("\(i) -> \(val)")
        for (j,val2) in str.enumerated() {
            // val2 should be from i postion instead starting from zero
        }
}
```

How to enumerate and set `j` position should start from `i`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dropFirst()` to create a view in the string starting with a specific position:

```swift
for (i,val) in str.enumerated() {
    print("i: \(i) -> \(val)")
    for (j, val2) in str.dropFirst(i).enumerated() {
        print("j: \(i+j) -> \(val2)")
    }
}
```

You need to add `i` in the second loop if you want to get the index corresponding to the original string, otherwise `j` will hold the index in the view created by `dropFirst()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for in` the `str.indices` and start inside loop based on outside loop.

```
let str = "abc"

for i in str.indices {
    for j in str[i...].indices {
        print(str[j])
    }
}
```

Output: `a b c b c c`

---

(Suggestion from [@LeoDabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus))

Comment: That's expected as enumerated() method returns an offset not an index. Note that every iteration you are unnecessarily offsetting the index from the startIndex. Btw you should extend StringProtocol or the collection itself to englobe substrings as well. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877538/2303865

Comment: `for index in str.indices {
    for idx in str[index...].indices { print(str[idx]) }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem statement correctly, the OP requires this -

> Hello
>  ello
>  llo
>  lo
>  o

We can use the [`suffix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2892530-suffix) method provided by Apple.

```
let str = "Hello"
var lengthOfString = str.count

for (i, val) in str.enumerated() {
    print(String(str.suffix(lengthOfString - i)))
}
```

We don't need the `val` in the for loop above, so we can rewrite the above for loop as below.

```
var str = "Hello"
var lengthOfString = str.count

for i in 0..<lengthOfString {
    print(String(str.suffix(lengthOfString - i)))
}
```

Both the above for loops will give the same desired output.