# Design loops in swift like php loops in html

Tags: php, html, css, sql, swift

I am quite new to swift, but I have worked a bit in php, html, css, sql and so on. In php I used to do these loops with html/css like below and filling out with data from my database. I know how to do loops, but do not know how to use them like I did in php

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array1); $i++) { ?>
  <div class="article">
     <h1 class="title"><?php echo $array1[$i] ?></h1>
     <p><?php echo $array2[$i] ?></p>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Are there anyway to do something like this in swift/xcode? Maybe I just need an alternative to the "div" in swift.

This might be a stupid question, but I still hope you can helt me :)

Comment: "I just need an alternative to the "div" in swift." That would ba an `NSView`/`UIView`. Although it really won't help to think of it that way, because the analogy really don't hold well. HTML is a declarative format for describing the structure of a web page. `UIKit`/`AppKit` don't work like that (although `SwiftUI` does). What you're probably looking for is a `UITableView`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift for loop: for index, element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028421/swift-for-loop-for-index-element-in-array)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You were right about the tableViews. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `enumerated`. The c-style `for` loop has been removed as from swift 3.
Working sample code

```
    for (index, _) in array1.enumerated() {
        print(array1[index])
    }
```

More details here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question might be a little confusing, but I already know how to do loops, what I do not know is how to use them to make a html-like structure in my app, like above. Hope that makes sense