# What is the term for the "current/temporary element" inside a For-loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I want to know the name of the "temporary variable" that you access inside a for-loop. It's not really language-specific, but here's my code in Swift:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
for number in array {
    print(number) /// what is this?
}
```

What is `number`, the "temporary variable" that is different in each iteration, known as?

Here are my attempts at describing it.

- The current iteration's element
- The current element

Then, what if I was looping over the array's indices? How would I refer to `number` in this case?

```
let list = [1, 2, 3]
for i in 0..<list.count {
    let number = list[i] /// what is this?
    print(number)
}
```

My attempts:

- The element of the `list` array at the current iteration's index
- The element of the `list` array at the loop's current iteration's index

Comment: @ aheze are you trying to iterate both index and element of an array?

Comment: code one & two both will print `element`(value) of an array. but first one you directly call the value of an array & second will call value via array index.

Comment: In both cases `number` is a local variable that exists in the scope of the `for` loop so it is not different from any other variable in that it exists in the scope it was declared.

Comment: It’s also known as *Index variable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's take one example.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
for number in array {
    print(number)
}
```

for the above case, the loop will print each number (element/Object) of the array(Not the index of the element).

It means if the array is
`[a,b,c,d]`,
it will print
`abcd`

For the second case, you are iterating loop over a range of array and then get the element based on an index

```
let list = [1, 2, 3]
for i in 0..<list.count {
    let number = list[i] /// what is this?
    print(number)
}
```

The above example, `i` is referred to the index of an array value and
`let number = list[i]` code will give you an element at the `i` index.

In last, If you want both indexes with the element within a single loop. You can use `.enumerated()`

Here is one example

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
for (index, number) in array.enumerated() {
    print("Array object/ Element Index :- ", index)
    print("Array object/ Element :- ", number)
}
```

Comment: "element at the `i` index" I think this is at close at it gets, thanks!

Comment: The element at an index refers to a value in the array and not to the variable it is assigned to.

Comment: Yes, I mean this. Just sentence word mistake. Thanks

Comment: @aheze be careful when using enumerated. It returns the offset not the index. If you use it with a slice of the collection it will probably crash your app. You should always use its indices. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877538/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, gotcha! Actually I was only trying to find out the academic term for the iterator thing (which seems to be called the "**Index variable**"). RajaKishan just gave a (very appreciated) extended answer.